# How can I do document-wide title case capitalization in KOMA-script?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titles, titlecaps

I'd like to use title case in KOMA-script-typeset title page and section titles.

Of course, I can do

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrreprt} % it's 3.32
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\title{\titlecap{The Beginning of the document}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \section{\titlecap{My title with caps}}
\end{document}
```

However, I'd like to have something idiomatic, say,

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\MakeTitleCase}
```

How can I automate title-casing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could patch `\chapterlinesformat`, `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`, `\sectionlinesformat`, `\sectioncatchphraseformat` and maybe `\minisec`:

```latex
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*\MakeTitleCase[1]{\titlecap{#1}}

\xpatchcmd\chapterlinesformat{#3}{\MakeTitleCase{#3}}{}{\clfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\chapterlineswithprefixformat{#3}{\MakeTitleCase{#3}}{}{\clwpfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\sectionlinesformat{#4}{\MakeTitleCase{#4}}{}{\slfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\sectioncatchphraseformat{#4}{\MakeTitleCase{#4}}{}{\scpfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\minisec{#1}{\MakeTitleCase{#1}}{}{\mspatchfailed}
```

For the title you can use

```latex
\newcommand*\originaltitle{}
\let\originaltitle\title
\renewcommand\title[1]{\originaltitle{\MakeTitleCase{#1}}}
```

With

```latex
\newcommand*\originaladdchaptertocentry{}
\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*\addchaptertocentry[2]{\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{\MakeTitleCase{#2}}}
```

only chapter entries will use `\MakeTitleCase` in TOC.

If all entries in TOC should use `\MakeTitleCase`:

```latex
\newcommand*\originaladdtocentrydefault{}
\let\originaladdtocentrydefault\addtocentrydefault
\renewcommand*\addtocentrydefault[3]{\originaladdtocentrydefault{#1}{#2}{\MakeTitleCase{#3}}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[version=last]{scrreprt} % it's 3.32
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*\MakeTitleCase[1]{\titlecap{#1}}

\xpatchcmd\chapterlinesformat{#3}{\MakeTitleCase{#3}}{}{\clfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\chapterlineswithprefixformat{#3}{\MakeTitleCase{#3}}{}{\clwpfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\sectionlinesformat{#4}{\MakeTitleCase{#4}}{}{\slfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\sectioncatchphraseformat{#4}{\MakeTitleCase{#4}}{}{\scpfpatchfailed}
\xpatchcmd\minisec{#1}{\MakeTitleCase{#1}}{}{\mspatchfailed}

\newcommand*\originaltitle{}
\let\originaltitle\title
\renewcommand\title[1]{\originaltitle{\MakeTitleCase{#1}}}


\newcommand*\originaladdtocentrydefault{}
\let\originaladdtocentrydefault\addtocentrydefault
\renewcommand*\addtocentrydefault[3]{\originaladdtocentrydefault{#1}{#2}{\MakeTitleCase{#3}}}

\title{The Beginning of the document}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter with caps}
\section{A section with caps}
\minisec{A minisec with caps}
\paragraph{A paragraph with caps}
Example text ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if the \*linesformat had one parent command, so that one shouldn't repeat the code.

Comment: I wonder how can this solution be extenden to clauses and subclauses from `scrjura`. I've tried adding `\xpatchcmd\Clauseformat{#1}{\MakeTitleCase{#1}}{}{\clfpatchfailed}%` but it does nothing, probably, because `title` is a key=val argument there.

Comment: The `title` key is completly different handled than a section heading. Maybe you can ask a new question including a MWE.